# finding roots of complex equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have here a complex equation:

$$z^2 - (7+j)z + 24 +j7 = 0$$

How do we get the roots of this equation? I started using the quadratic formula $-b \pm \sqrt{ b^2-4ac}\over 2$, but it yielded too much complexity on it. Is there any way to directly attack this? Thanks.

Comment: What is $j$ (imaginary unit?). How can the solution be too complex (complicated?)

Comment: yes j is imaginary unit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can [complete the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square), that is, write $z^2-(7+j)z$ as the beginning of the expansion of
$$
\left(z-\frac12(7+j)\right)^2.
$$
This yields
$$
z^2-(7+j)z+24+7j=\left(z-\tfrac12(7+j)\right)^2-u,
$$
with
$$
u=\tfrac14(7+j)^2-24-7j.
$$
But $u=v^2$ for some complex number $v$, hence the equation to solve is equivalent to
$$
\left(z-\tfrac12(7+j)\right)^2-v^2=0,
$$
that is,
$$
\left(z-\tfrac12(7+j)-v\right)\cdot\left(z-\tfrac12(7+j)+v\right)=0,
$$
which yields the two solutions
$$
z=\tfrac12(7+j)\pm v.
$$
It remains to compute $v$...

Comment: I will delete my answer because it does not add anything relevant to yours.

Answer (score 3):

Although we do find the roots, the following is mainly a spoof of school algebra.

In school algebra, students are expected to solve very special equations of the form $ax^2+bx +c=0$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers, by *factoring*.  The Quadratic Formula, and even the Rational Roots Theorem,  are withheld from them, as that would make the problem too simple.

The process they are taught involves factoring $a$ and $c$, and fiddling a bit to try to produce $-b$.  They are only given quadratics that yield to this process.

Let's play that game with our equation, to see whether we are dealing with a variant of a school problem.  So we factor $24+7i$ in the *Gaussian integers*.  Note that $(24+7i)(24-7i)=625$.  If you have done some computations with Gaussian integers, you will see that the Gaussian primes involved in the factorization are $2\pm i$ (and associates, but we needn't worry about these). Also, since $5$ does not divide $24+7i$, we know that $24+7i$ must be an associate of $(2\pm i)^4$. Pretty quickly we find that $24+7i=-i(2+i)^4$.

Now let's find two Gaussian integers whose product is $-i(2+i)^4$ and whose sum is $7+i$. Note that $(2+i)^2=3+4i$ and $-i(2+i)^2=4-3i$. Their sum is $7+i$, so we have found the roots.

Comment: in your 4th paragraph, you write "Also, since $24+7i$ does not divide $24+7i$...". I assume this is a typo.

Comment: @Mark Beadles: Thanks very much for careful reading! Yes, I meant since $5$ does not divide $24+7i$.  That rules out $2+i$ and $2-i$ *both* appearing in the prime factorization.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the constant term $(24 + 7j)$ is one-half of the square of the $7 + j$ coefficient. This suggests writing $z = (7 + j)w$, and the equation becomes
$$(48 + 14j) w^2 - (48 + 14j)w + (24 + 7j) = 0$$
Divide through by $(24 + 7j)$ and you get
$$2w^2 - 2w + 1 = 0$$
By the quadratic formula this has roots ${1 \over 2} \pm {j \over 2}$.
So the roots of the original equation are $(7 + j) ({1 \over 2} \pm {j \over 2})$, or in other words $3 + 4j$ and $4 - 3j$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote $z$ as : $z=a+jb$ , then we have :

$a^2-b^2+2abj-(7+j)(a+bj)+24+7j=0 \Rightarrow$

$\Rightarrow a^2-b^2+2abj - (7a+7bj+aj-b)+24+7j=0$

So , you have to solve following system of equations :

$\begin{cases}
 a^2-b^2-7a+b+24=0 \\
  2ab-7b-a+7=0\\
 \end{cases}$